# How to limit view to authenticated user in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework application.
Authentication is performed through a login method:

```
def login(self, request):
    user = find_my_user(request)
    user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    login(request, user)
    return Response({"status": "ok"})
```

Authentication works fin.

I have a ViewSet having a list_route() that need authenticated user to be used.
Here is the code:

```
class CommonView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @list_route()
    @authentication_classes(SessionAuthentication)
    @permission_classes(IsAuthenticated)
    def connected(self, request):
        return Response({"status": "ok"})
```

Even if the user is not authenticated (no session cookie), the action is performed.

As a work around, I've performed it like that :

```
class CommonView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @list_route()
    def connected(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Response({"status": "ok"})
        else:
            return Response({"status": "ko", "message": "Unauthenticated"})
```

But I feel it could be cleaner, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

**You can create a custom `ListRouteIsAuthenticated` permission class  inheriting from `BasePermission` class which will deny any permission to unauthenticated users for any request in the `list` route.**

For `detail` route requests, it will allow unrestricted access, regardless of if the request was authenticated or unauthenticated.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import  BasePermission

class ListRouteIsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    """
    Custom Permission Class which authenticates a request for `list` route
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == 'list':
            return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated() #  check user is authenticated for 'list' route requests
        return True # no authentication check otherwise
```

Then in your viewset, you need to define this permission class.

```
class CommonView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    permission_classes = [ListRouteIsAuthenticated]
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, add an attribute:

```
class CommonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Comment: Indeed, however it will be applied to all method inside the View. I just need to apply it to some of them,